# Can we post messages directly on facebook user profile(wall) using facebook API's who are not friends

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Just wanted to know whether we can post messages directly on facebook user profile(wall) using Facebook API's who are not friends. Currently we have the friends Facebook username only with us

example: `<firstname.lastname>` valid facebook username

Comment: No, this is not possible. The closest thing you'd be able to do is tag users in a post, but even that is limited to users who are friends.